# htaccess rewrite causes loop if 404

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I know there are hundreds of posts on here about htaccess but I can't seem to find one that matches my situation.

I have two rewrite rules happening:

The first turns example.com/filename.php into example.com/filename/ as well as example.com/filenameA-filenameB.php to example.com/filenameA/filenameB/

The second adds a trailing slash to the end of the requested URL, if there isn't one.

Everything works great... until you enter an incorrect URL, such as example.com/foo or example.com/foo/ where foo.php doesn't exist. I get "The page isn't redirecting properly" and the address bar shows "example.com/foo.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php...". I just want to get a 404 so I can redirect to the 404 page but nothing I try seems to be working.

Thanks for your help!

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)//?$ $1-$2.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)//?$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: what is `//?` supposed to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a condition in your redirect that things ending with `.php` won't get redirected:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

After the first rewrite, the URI ends up being `/foo.php`, and if foo.php doesn't exist, the second rule gets applied because it also doesn't end with a `/`, this you get redirected to http://example.com/foo.php/, then the first set of rules change it to `/foo.php.php`, and it doesn't exist and doesn't end a slash, so the second rule gets applied, redirecting you to http://example.com/foo.php.php/ etc. etc.

---

EDIT:

> When non existent PHP files are requested from the server, it doesn't respond with a 404 but rather a "no input file selected" message.

You could try adding this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule \.php$ - [R=404]
```

This is more or less what you had read about, but the rule matches against anything ending with .php and redirects you to the 404 page.

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you so much for the help.
I have an additional thing that is happening, that I'm hoping you can help with. When non existent PHP files are requested from the server, it doesn't respond with a 404 but rather a "no input file selected" message. I have read about this and the workaround seems to look like this:
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteRule ^.+\.php$ /404
but I can't figure out where that logic should go among these other conditions.

Comment: That's giving me a 500 server config error. Sorry to be a pain, I wish I better understood how this worked.